# GWT label with line breaks

Tags: gwt

GWT Label widgets iterprets everything as text, not as html tags - that's good, but I would like it to interpret `\n` as a `<br />` how do i do that.

I would make subclass, but I cant find what to override to achieve this behaviour

(I could use HTML widget, but it would interpret all tags - and all I need is an line brak)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use an HTML widget and set its value using a `SafeHtml` constructed with [`SafeHtmlBuilder.appendEscapedLines`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlBuilder.html#appendEscapedLines%28java.lang.String%29):

```
HTML label = new HTML(new SafeHtmlBuilder().appendEscapedLines("foo<bar\nbaz>quux").toSafeHtml());
```

(alternatively, you can `split("\n", -1)` your text, call `SafeHtml.htmlEscape` on each part and join them back with a `<br>`, that's what `appendEscapedLines` does)

Answer (score 19):

Another option is to use CSS, which may be sufficient in some cases where this problem emerges.

Add the CSS attribute `white-space: pre` or `pre-wrap` in the area where you display the text. It will ensure that line breaks are respected when rendering the document.

This approach has the potential to reduce some complexity, e.g. the processing of input where `\n` is replaced with `<br/>`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML` class to achieve this or simply write,

```
Label label = new HTML("// html code you wnat to write");
```

Comment: The thing I don't understand about it is: Why would someone use HTML tags, if one doesn't want them to be treated as HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The problem to display multi-line text with HTML in XML files is that we are not allowed to use character < in the content. For example the below code cannot be compiled:

```
<g:HTML HTML="Line 1<br />Line2<br />Line 3" />
```

In my case, I declare that text as a i18n string then use in html

```
<ui:with field='ln' type='com.mycompany.i18n.LocalizableStrings'/>

<g:HTML HTML="{ln.EXPLAINATION}" />
```