# GWT Label with line breaks without HTML, is this possible?

Tags: java, gwt

I need to insert a line break into a GWT Label. `<br>` doesn't work, neither does `\n` or `\u000a` (which also happens to be an illegal escape character when I try to add it as a String literal - anyone know why?)

Yes, I could make two separate labels, but I need to do this on about 30 Labels and I'm hoping there's a faster way to solve this problem.

I cannot use HTML at all, not even safeHtml is allowed. I know, it's easy to do this in HTML as described here: [GWT label with line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185077/gwt-label-with-line-breaks)

If you can prove that it's impossible, I'll accept that as an answer too (Is that ok? It seems like that should be ok. It seems like we should have some sort of special way to accept answers that verify that something's impossible, maybe I should mention that in Meta).

Answer (score 5):

You could try a little trick. Replace all spaces with a non-breaking space, then replace the new-line character with a space. At last, set the `Label` width to 1% to force a line break at any place possible (which are now spaces that were replacement for new-line characters).

```
private Label getMultilineLabel(String text) {
    Label label = new Label(text.replaceAll(" +", "\u00a0").replaceAll("\n", " "));
    label.setWidth("1%");
    return label;
}
```

Then

```
getMultilineLabel("Some quite long text\nwith a line break.");
```

gives

```
Some quite long text
with a line break.
```

Comment: I applaud you for the hack. If my boss approves this, I'll be amazed. But I'll ask.